# how to make multiple folders in python at once for windows

Tags: python

Hey I am new to programming can anyone help point me in the right direction ? I am trying to make multiple folders at one for a sorting program pretty much checking if the folder exists and if it doesn't make one named after the file type its sorting. I was looking it up and found some code but I don't understand where on the computer it is writing to. Here is the code I found online:

```
import os

# define the name of the directory to be created
path = "/tmp/year/month/week/day"

try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s" % path)
```

Comment: path = r"D:\test\NewFolderName"

Comment: so if i want to write to 'C:\Users\User\Pictures\1sort' it would look like path = 'C:\Users\User\Pictures\1sort\NewFolderName'

Comment: almost, don't forget the "r" in front, so it would be: path = r'C:\Users\User\Pictures\1sort\NewFolderName' because otherwise some charcter combinations in your string might be interpreted wrongly. For example test this to see the difference: print("\0_folder") and print(r"\0_folder")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create multiple folders create a list of folder names and set the path to the parent-folder:

```
import os

# define the name of the directory to be created
path = r"D:\test"
lst_folders = [r"Folder_A", r"Folder_B", r"Folder_C"]

for new_folder in lst_folders:
    print(new_folder)
    path_new = os.path.join(path, new_folder)
    
    try:
        os.makedirs(path_new)
    except OSError:
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
    else:
        print ("Successfully created the directory %s" % path)
```

Comment: this works great now i need to learn how to search lets say "folder_c" for .arw files and .jpeg files and sort one into "folder_a" and the other into "folder_b" and if there are other file types leave them in "folder_c" any ideas? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try this also

```
import os

path = "parent"

for new in range(5):
    print(f'{path}/child_{new}')
    try:
        os.makedirs(f'{path}/child_{new}')
    except OSError:
        print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
    else:
        print ("Successfully created the directory %s" % path)
```

Comment: could you answer my comment on the other answer Thank You.